# Excluding @user replies in Twitterizer

Tags: c#, twitter, twitterizer

I'm using the excellent Twitterizer to get a user's timeline, however I'd like to exclude @user replies from this returned collection.

The Twitter API offers a 'exclude_replies' parameter, but I can't find anything similar in the [Twitterizer documentation](http://www.twitterizer.net/documentation/).

Is there any way in which I can do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't appear as though we have implemented that parameter yet. I've logged it as [Issue 111](http://pm.twitterizer.net/issues/111).

Answer (score 1):

You might have to filter the replies once you've got them. Presumably you have a  [`TwitterStatusCollection`](http://www.twitterizer.net/documentation/html/T_Twitterizer_TwitterStatusCollection.htm). There are some likely looking properties in each [`TwitterStatus`](http://www.twitterizer.net/documentation/html/T_Twitterizer_TwitterStatus.htm), such as `InReplyToUserID`.

You could presumably (I haven't tried it) do something like this:

```
var filtered = myTimeline.Where(s => s.InReplyToUserID == null);
```

Or, failing that, filter out any statuses with the "@..." pattern in the text.